# Cannot update zesty release

Tags: ubuntu

When I try to use sudo apt-get update, I get the following error:

```
E: The repository 'http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

what can I do to update Ubuntu correctly?

I'm on Ubuntu 17.04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty) has reached the end of its life (see the [releases page on the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) for details), so it’s no longer available from the repositories.

You have two options:

- upgrade to 17.10 (this is the better solution);
- replace `de.archive.ubuntu.com` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` with `old-releases.ubuntu.com`.

The second option will allow `apt-get update` to finish, but you won’t get any new updates. In particular, you won’t get updates addressing [Meltdown and Spectre](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2018/01/04/ubuntu-updates-for-the-meltdown-spectre-vulnerabilities/).

Comment: Indeed @GAD3R, thanks, I wondered about that...

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 17.04 STS had a 9-month lifetime which expired a week ago.  The Ubuntu people recommend upgrading to 17.10, which is another short-term support release.  Your next LTS release will be 18.04, due later this year.

## Further reading

- Steve Langasek (2018-01-05). *[Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty Zapus) reaches End of Life on January 13, 2018](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2018-January/000227.html)*. lists.ubuntu.com.
- *[Releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)*. Ubuntu wiki.